# Почему цвет названия приложения в уведомлении отображается неправильно?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notification

У меня задан в colors цвет

```xml
    <color name="secondaryColor">#ffca28</color>
```

[image: <color name="secondaryColor">#ffca28</color>]

Я хочу чтобы мой заголовок приложения в уведомлениях выглядел так

[image: Пример уведомления]

Я задаю цвет в настройках уведомления

```kotlin
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Time keeper alarm")
                  .........

            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text))
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.secondaryColor))

        val manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        manager.notify(999, builder.build())
```

Но когда уведомление всплывает или находится в стеке уведомлений, цвет заголовка вообще не такой даже близко. Почему так? И как это исправить?

[image: Скриншот уведомления]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setColorized(boolean)

Comment: К сожалению не помогло